# What parts of chicken contain suet?

Tags: chicken

I don’t know if suet is the right term but I think i think chicken has those white bits which are referred to as suet in meat.  What parts of chicken has this?  I think I like it.

Comment: *Suet* is the hard fat that's found around the loins and kidneys of cows and sheep.  Chickens do not have "suet."  They do have fat.  Are you interested in knowing where to find fat on chickens?